# Egguation of this locus

Tags: locus

Recently I saw [this](https://youtube.com/shorts/FFpiZx1vQmk) YouTube video where an egg shape is drawn using a construction similar to that of an ellipse.

So I was wondering about the equation of this shape. Can we describe it by just using the fact that it is the locus of points such that the sum of distances from 3 points remain constant? How does the shape vary depending on the position of the third point?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-ellipse looks like a good place to start your investigation.

Comment: @GerryMyerson oh I didn't know that. Thanks for the reference....seems interesting

Comment: Maybe [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1483195/is-there-a-general-equation-for-an-n-ellipse) is useful.